# Is Using Robocopy /B pointless as an Administrator?

Tags: robocopy

From what I can tell, the /B switch only seems useful to grant a limited user the ability to make backups. Am I correct on this?

Comment: Indeed, robocopy in backup mode is basically pointless unless your a standard user with backup rights. Source: http://2clickfix.com/robocopy-backup-mode/

Comment: There's no source for your source and my own findings contradict that it's useless as administrator. Even Administrator can be locked out of folders if a user has ability to change security, in which case backup mode can be used to backup the folder.